# reading from textfile and then inserting record to oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi I have a table student which have few null fields in it. Student# is primary key in this table. I want to insert data into a table Officerecord by selecting data from student table, filling the null fields from a excel or doc file and inserting into Officerecord table.

```
Student
=======
Student #   name     Course    age
1            Jess     ENG       19
2            Jane               20
3            Kevin    MAT       19
4            Rob                21
```

In above table course data is missing for student 2 and student 4. We have a course file which contains student # and course data. I want to read data from file and inserting this record to "Officerecord" Table which looks like as below:

```
Officerecord
===========

OFFICE#        STUDENT#           COURSE
```

While inserting data in this table i want no row should contain null value related to student.

Please help.

Comment: Where is the "course file"? Is this a flat file on the database server? Or on some client machine? Can you load the data from this file into a new table and then merge the data into your `student` table?

Comment: This is a word file on my desktop. No i cannot load file into a table.

Comment: Do you literally mean a Word file (not a text file but a binary file in Microsoft Word's proprietary format)?  Can you save it as a text file?  Can you move the file to the database server?  PL/SQL runs on the database server so it only has access to resources on the database server.  If you can't load the data into a table and can't move the file to the database server, you can't read it using PL/SQL.  You could write an application that would run on your desktop that would read the file, connect to the database, and update the table.  But that would not be in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Developer can import Excel files (.xls / .xlsx) directly into a table, but you will need to define the table structure ahead of time.  It's as simple as right clicking the table in the list, selecting import  data, selecting the file, then matching up the excel columns with the table columns.

Ideally you would use an external table for importing, but I don't believe you can easily maneuver spreadsheets using one.

In any event, once you have loaded both sets of data, you can do a simple update on your Student table to fill in the nulls.

```
UPDATE Student
SET (COURSE) =
( SELECT COURSE
  FROM Officerecord
  WHERE Student.Student# = Officerecord.Student# )
WHERE COURSE IS NULL;
```

Note that this will fail if you have two entries in Officerecord for a single student, but your example isn't clear with how you'd want to handle such a situation.

Comment: Here are the steps: Create a new table in SQL Developer or SQL, r-click on the table in SQL Developer, select Import Data option then you will see many different formats that can be used to export data to your table from a file.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the text from the source datafile and create a script from it which is a series of update statements.

A programmers file editor should help you here - recortd a macro that turns raw data in to statments of the form
`update student set course = 'myCourse' where StudentNo = 99 and course is null;`

Answer (score 0):

you can create an external table for office_records file and join this table with students table and make necessary changes to input to final office_records table.

The advantage of external table is you can just replace the file when data changes, you need not go for loading the file manually.

This helps even if the user does not have the access/knowledge of inserting records from file using sql developer or Toad.